# How to compile and run C# apps on macOS

Tags: c#, .net, macos

I'm new to C# on Mac and decided to ask a question because I don't know how to pick up the pieces.

I installed Visual Studio on Mac, wrote some app and compiled it.

My question is how to compile a C# app and run it within a macOS. Does the user need a .NET framework to be pre-installed to be able to run my applications? Does it translate C# code to the native code?

Please, could someone give me a link, explanation, article or documentation?

Comment: I don't think this one merits the downvotes - in my mind, it is a legit question with an answer, that's albeit, not a programming directly but more environment related.

Comment: Matt, Thank you very much for your support. I always thought that every question deserves the answer no matter whether stupid it or too easy for someone. But someone always thinks different.

Comment: @Vlad: _"I always thought that every question deserves the answer..."_ -- you are of course welcome to your opinion. However, Stack Overflow community guidelines are very clear on this point. There are _many_ kinds of questions that do _not_ deserve an answer and _should_ be closed. Including those that show no evidence of research, those which are seeking a reference to some third-party resource, and especially those which have already been answered on Stack Overflow. Your question fits _all_ of those criteria, making it very low quality by SO standards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to program and code in .net core.

'Traditional' .NET Framework programs only run on Windows systems as they require the .NET framework.
When you write any .NET code, the compiler only generates intermediary code (I think they call it IL) for the local interpreter to run, not assembly that can run straight on a processor in the traditional sense.

A few years ago however, Microsoft introduced .NET core which, much like Java, has interpreters for many different operating systems.

As long as you reference .NET core namespaces and have the interpreter running on the target OS, it should work fine.

Comment: In case this helps anybody: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos

Answer (score 5):

Matt’s answer is correct. Target the .Net Core framework if you expect to deploy to other Macs. But those Macs will need to have the .Net core framework installed in order to run you app.

Please see the link below for Mac OS requirements regarding.Net Core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/macos-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x